# How to increase "Max Request Headers Total Size" of the .Net application running in the azure App Services?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a .net 6 application running in the Azure App Services. The operation system is Windows in the Azure App Services. According to the research Ive done, Azure uses IIS by default. In this scenario, how can I increase the maximum size of the headers? Thanks in advance.

Before researching, I thought Azure was using Kestrel by default and I thought I could fix this in code.

Comment: IIS will allow you to use a `web.config` file for such cases, which should be included in your C# project by default. You can add the `<HeaderLimit>` element to it and specify a custom size.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer I tried 2 ways : First is : <security> <requestFiltering> <requestLimits maxRequestHeadersTotalSize="16384" /> </requestFiltering> </security> Second one is : <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits>
            <headerLimits >
              <add header="*" sizeLimit="2048" />
            </headerLimits>
          </requestLimits>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security> Both did not work. Did I write something wrong?

Comment: @TayfunArslan -- Were you able to resolve this issue? The web.config change is not working for me either.

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config` you'll need the following structure:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits>
               <headerLimits>
                  <add header="Authorization" sizeLimit="4096" />
               </headerLimits>
            </requestLimits>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I don't think a wildcard for the header will work. So this comes with the assumption that the header causing the issues is known else it would be weird to send such a huge payload that is ignored anyway.

Comment: I added the conf below to test:

`<security>
     <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits>
            <headerLimits>
              <add header="Test-Header" sizeLimit="50000"/>
            </headerLimits>
          </requestLimits>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>`

But I still got the problem. I think this limits the headers size but It doesnt increase max size. And I need to increase for the sum of all headers.

I also tried this:
`<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestHeadersTotalSize="1048576" />
  </system.web>`

But It is also not working.

Comment: Eek that's large. I think you are running against a different limit. Not sure how and if you can bypass it.

Comment: Values are sample values. My goal is increase value to 64kb